# Youtube video on react page

Tags: reactjs

What's the best way to display a youtube video in react?

I tried using the [react.video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react.video) module, but it's outdated and it's not working properly.

I tried using the documentation but I get this error

> ./node_modules/react.video/index.js
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tvojakeva/Desktop/stack/test/node_modules/react.video/index.js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message appears because the node module isn't installed.

I would use [ReactPlayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) in your position.

```
import ReactVideo from 'react.video';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactVideo 
      url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOna9EPQJFA'
      />
    </div>
  ) 
}

export default App
```